# how to Get a Process CurrentThreadId in C#?

Tags: c#, process

i want to get one process CurrentThreadId.
i can get my application Current Thread ID with AppDomain.GetCurrentThreadId();
for example i want to get Task Manager CurrentThreadId.

```
var proces = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("taskmgr");
            proces[0].Threads//write code for get currentThreadID?
```

Comment: Makes no sense, a process has multiple threads.

Comment: Please tell us more on what you want to do. Perhaps a solution can be found easily. Why do you want to retrieve the current thread id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the Process Id, you are already on the right track!

Here is an example:

```
    public void GetProcessId()
    {
        var processList = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("taskmgr");

        // note that you get a list, there may be multiple processes returned
        foreach (var process in processList)
        {
            // print out the process id
            System.Console.WriteLine("Process Id=" + process.Id);
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank friends.
i want to hook one process for GetMessage.

    SetWindowsHookEx((int)HookType.WH_GETMESSAGE, s_Delegate, a, TaskMGRCurrentThreadId);

but I can only Hook My Application:

    SetWindowsHookEx((int)HookType.WH_GETMESSAGE, s_Delegate, a, (int)AppDomain.GetCurrentThreadId());

Comment: Strange. You want to hook into another process but do not know how the currentThreadId behaves? What you are trying here will probably fail.

Answer (score 3):

You can't.

A process can (and usually does) have more than one thread. The "current" thread changes constantly - potentially many times each second.

Asking for the current thread only makes sense for your own process.

Comment: ... and it is possible that multiple threads of a process could be "current" on a multicore system.